# How do I get OpenJDK 11 from Maven?

Tags: maven, docker, openjdk-11

I'm building a Docker web application and I need to assemble a Docker image with the following packages, in order:

- openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
- apache-tomcat-9.0.27.tar.gz -- In Maven as: org.apache.tomcat:tomcat:9.0.27
- jcc-11.5.0.0.jar -- In Maven as: com.ibm.db2:jcc:11.5.0.0
- my-app.tar.gz -- This is build by Maven.

So, in the docker image I first install Java, then Tomcat, then the JDBC driver for DB2, and finally my web app on top of it. I can get all of them from Maven, except the first one: the OpenJDK.

If it's not in Maven, do I need to include the whole OpenJDK 11 in my git repository, so it's there for the docker build?

Maybe, I'm doing this the wrong way, but I want to make sure the docker build works in **any** machine it runs. I'm thinking of CI/CD.

Comment: Don't put the JDK into your git repository.

Comment: Update your Tomcat version.

Comment: @Michael-O If that solved my problem I would do it in a sec. The OpenJDK download is the issue for me. Don't know how Maven can do it.

Comment: Maven can't do it. You have to use bash commands to install the jdk at the start of your dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Docker image for OpenJDK 11

```
FROM openjdk:11
```

Or you can use Alpine base image if you need a smaller OpenJDK 11 image

```
FROM openjdk:11-alpine
```

In this way you'll already have the OpenJDK 11 in your container, without to use Maven to get it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. For security reasons I'm forced to use the Redhat base image the IT department provides. I comes bare with no packages installed at all, so I need to install Java there.